# Modify the number of entries in the list to choose from for bookmarking a site in Firefox

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

I am wondering if it is possible to change the number of entries in the list which appears when in Firefox you right click on a tab and choose "add to bookmarks".

That's because I use to categorize a lot of bookmarks and the standard choice of 5 entries is too small. Of course the idea is to not have to click on "choose" further down following the menu.

Comment: What version of Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

I have two answers for you, although I'll admit that both miss the mark slightly.

The first is that you can get complete control by pressing `CTRL + B` to open the bookmarks sidebar, and the you can simply drag a tab into the folder of your choosing. By its nature this will show you all the bookmark folders you have.

The latter is that the 5 entries is probably hard-coded, after a look around about:config, however you might be able to find a firefox extension that enhances bookmark adding:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/extensions/bookmarks

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for you help, this helps. By the way my version of ff is 3.6.17. Thanks and cheers, Roberto